# (Python) How can I create a dictionary from a list, assigning the values in a second list as its keys?

Tags: python

I'm very new to learning Python and as part of trying to get more familiar with what it, I've been messing around with writing little bits of code that do things not explicitly taught in source I'm learning from but use the same concepts.

One thing that I was trying to do was have two lists, for example `list=["apple", "banana", "orange", "grape"]` and `otherlist=["ok", "good", "better", "best"]` and using them to create a dictionary where the end result was `dict={"ok":"apple","good":"banana","better":"orange","best":"grape"}`.

But I couldn't figure out how to do it. To my best understanding, I'd have to iterate through both lists sort of...in parallel so as to assign the first string in 'otherlist' as the key for the first string in 'list', and so on.

I tried doing some kind of for loop, as in

```
for word in otherlist:
    dict[word]=???
```

Where the "???" is where I get stuck, a since I can't figure out how to iterate through 'list' at the same time. Any help for this curious noob is appreciated! :)

Comment: If this question is not a duplicate, i eat my hat.

Answer (score 5):

First of all avoid using the object types as variable names like `list`, you may either use a meaningful one or something like `list1`, `list2`, etc.

```
list1 = ["apple", "banana", "orange", "grape"]
list2 = ["ok", "good", "better", "best"]
```

In order to combined 2 lists (assuming to be of equal size) you may use `zip` and then cast the output to `dict` as :

```
d = dict(zip(list2, list1))
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Zip both lists together:

   ```
   list=["apple", "banana", "orange", "grape"]
   otherlist=["ok", "good", "better", "best"]
   zip(list, otherlist)
   [('apple', 'ok'), ('banana', 'good'), ('orange', 'better'), ('grape', 'best')]
   ```
2. Call `dict` on the result to create a dictionary of these pairs.

   ```
   dict(zip(list, otherlist))
   {'orange': 'better', 'grape': 'best', 'apple': 'ok', 'banana': 'good'}
   ```

Note: You have to make sure that the elements of the first list are unique, otherwise the last element wins.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
mydict = dict()
for x in max(len(list), len(otherlist)):
    mydict[list[x]] = otherlist[x]
```